# How to delete/remove an item from normalized state?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngxs

I have the following state structure:

```
{ entities:
1: {name: "Basketball", id: "1", leagues: Array(3)}
2: {name: "Volleyball", id: "2", leagues: Array(3)}
3: {name: "Soccer", id: "3", leagues: Array(0)}
}
```

Now I just want to remove an item with the id '3' lets say.

The following does not work:

```
const state = ctx.getState();
    delete state.entities[action.id];

    ctx.setState(
      patch<SportTypeStateModel>({
        entities: {...state.entities},
        IDs: state.IDs.filter(id => id !== action.id)
      })
    );
```

It throws the following error:

```
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot delete property '3' of [object Object]`
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Your structure seems to be missing brackets. What is 'entities'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to understand why this error occurs.

NGXS uses `deepFreeze` under the hood in the development mode to `Object.freeze` your state (and deeply nested objects/arrays) to prevent unpredictable mutations.

You can check it up by calling `Object.isFrozen`:

```js
const state = ctx.getState();
console.log(Object.isFrozen(state.entities));
delete state.entities[action.id];
```

**I understood your point that `entities` is not an array, but an object.**

So the problem is once an object has been frozen there is no way to unfreeze it. What do we have to do? We have to unfreeze the state object itself, the `entities` object and its children:

```js
const state = ctx.getState();
const newState = { ...state, entities: { ...state.entities }};
for (const key of Object.keys(newState.entities)) {
  newState.entities[key] = { ...newState.entities[key] };
}
console.log(Object.isFrozen(newState.entities));
delete newState.entities[action.id];
```

**I do not like this code so don't throw stones at me :)** I think you can search for some packages like `deep-unfreeze` to be more declarative. Oh, I forgot about the `IDs` property. The final code is:

```js
ctx.setState(state => {
  const newState = {
    entities: { ...state.entities },
    IDs: state.IDs.filter(id => id !== action.id)
  };
  for (const key of Object.keys(newState.entities)) {
    newState.entities[key] = { ...newState.entities[key] };
  }
  delete newState.entities[action.id];
  return newState;
});
```

P.S. checked it locally.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need to do. I’m surprised there isn’t more information about how to do this operation with a normalized entity object. The pain because when a single entity object contains array properties such as leagues: [] and each league object contains teams[] property. I could use lodash cloneDeep() there to get everything copied, but not sure if I should, especially since I have three pieces of store for sport types, leagues and then teams, and each of those entities has a reference property to the parent. Great explanation!

Comment: @O.MeeKoh do I need to update my answer and give some more explanation about some part, that you need, thus this answer could be accepted?

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter use instead of delete;

```
newEntities = state.entities.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);

ctx.setState(
      patch<SportTypeStateModel>({
        entities: {...newEntities },
        IDs: state.IDs.filter(id => id !== action.id)
      })
    );
```

Comment: it is not an array. It is an object

Comment: @Poldo I think it should be `state.entities.filter((item) => item.id !== action.id);`

and also correct `IDs: state.IDs.filter(id => id !== action.id)` similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be just to filter the existing state and patch.

```
const state = ctx.getState();
ctx.patchState({
  entities: [...state.entities.filter(e => e.id !== action.id)],
  IDs: [...state.IDs.filter(i => i !== action.id)]
}
```

The state model you're using isn't listed here - but if you are storing the entity, it'd be neater to model the `IDs` property as a `@Selector` rather than part of the state, since it is just a projection of what is in the entities list e.g.

```
@Selector()
static IDs(state: YourStateModel) {
  return state.entities.map(e => e.id);
}
```

This means it's always based on the current `state.entites` value, and you don't need to maintain two lists.